# Function signature is not automatically widened if passed as an argument

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, signature

I'm trying to create a higher-order function that accepts a number of functions with a specific signature. The signature, in this case, is any function that accepts exactly one parameter that implements a certain interface. Say, `Foo`:

```js
interface Foo {
    foo: string
}

function higherOrderStuff(funs: ((foo: Foo) => void)[]) {
    // do higher order stuff
}
```

However, to facilitate in the type checking, some functions use *intersections* of the original interface. Like so:

```js
type MyFoo = Foo & {
    foo: 'bar'
};

function myFunction(foo: MyFoo) {
    // do my stuff
}
```

Unfortunately, passing these functions to the higher-order wrapper yields an error:

```js
higherOrderStuff([myFunction]); // compiler error
```

```
TS2322: Type '(foo: MyFoo) => void' is not assignable to type '(foo: Foo) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'foo' and 'foo' are incompatible.
    Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'MyFoo'.
      Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type '{ foo: "bar"; }'.
        Types of property 'foo' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"bar"'.
```

And the error is right: `Foo` isn't assignable to `MyFoo`. In fact, I'm doing the opposite for a reason.

More strangely, if I try something different and pass around anything other than a function, the same scenario works as expected.

```js
function doStuffWithFoos(foos: Foo[]) {
    // do stuff
}

const myFoo: MyFoo = { foo: 'bar' };

doStuffWithFoos([myFoo]); // no squiggly line
```

So, why is it that arguments are correctly widened, while arguments of function arguments are not?

An explicit cast fixes the error, but it seems like it shouldn't be required to me.

```js
higherOrderStuff([myFunction as (foo: Foo) => void]); // this works
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error happens because functions are *contravariant* in their parameter types, which basically means that if you're passing a function that takes a parameter of type `T`, you can't pass a function that takes a parameter of a subtype of `T` instead (is supertype is fine though).

As an example in your code, say you implement `higherOrderStuff` by passing an object `{foo: 'not-bar'}` to each of the functions in `funs`:

```
interface Foo {
  foo: string
}

function higherOrderStuff(funs: ((foo: Foo) => void)[]) {
  return funs.map(f => f({foo: 'not-bar'}))
}
```

Since `MyFoo` has the narrower type `{foo: bar}` due to

```
type MyFoo = Foo & {
  foo: 'bar'
};
```

you can define a `myFunction` that depends on its parameter having this narrower type:

```
function myFunction(foo: MyFoo) {
  const shouldBeBar = foo.foo // inferred type: 'bar'
  const barObject = {bar: () => 42}
  const barFunction = barObject[shouldBeBar]
  return barFunction() // should return 42
}
```

Everything is still type correct, and because `shouldBeBar` can only be `bar`, `barFunction` will be a function returning 42.

But if you now run

```
console.log(higherOrderStuff([myFunction]))
```

it will end up calling `myFunction({foo: 'not-bar'})`, which will cause `barFunction` to end up `undefined` and throw a runtime error.

This is what the type error tries to prevent from happening.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIyYBcyAzmFKAOa4C%20uuMAriAmMOiMgBbDU9oAeSgATaAGUwzGDAAULEGVJyFJNJgCUyALwA%20ZADd0wUZoDaAXW14CUCNKjdFZAHQBbOAAcFug-OwidFIAchB0MABaACM4KBC6TU16RjAATy8UAFk0jCwdDSwAMhx8QnUQ2Pj6AG5GRXZObndc1kauNWDkHLybMoQuCnIedGYAG1EAIQhJuN1y9Fcg5AB6FeRQGGh7UWR0zNCqkP7BsGQqoWiAKwh2eewqlW19ZAAWACYGAgGlM6rUNocLjzC7XW5gcxkEbjKYzOKWMr2Rzcf6AppybRrYajCbIJHMJxvd4pXA-MjoMYQVxjdDUOR8ATCMSSaSyOTmFoAthAkDWZJAA)

To understand co- and contravariance, a fruit-and-juicer analogy may be helpful.

If you ask for a piece of fruit, it's fine to get a subtype orange, whereas if you ask for an orange, you don't just want to get any sort of fruit. This is covariance.

Now consider you need  a generic fruit juicer (i.e. a function from fruit to juice), then it's not okay to get an orange juicer, as you might want to juice a pineapple as well. On the other hand, if you ask for an orange juicer, a generic fruit juicer will do just fine. You could say that the juicer is contravariant in the type of things it juices.

Comment: Could you pls recommend an article or book about covariance and contravariance ? This is magic for me, I only understand it on some intuition level

Comment: @captain-yossarian Unfortunately, I've never found a great explanation. Usually they are rather abstract or overly wordy. This one is kind of okay: https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: thanks, I have already read this article, even have it in my bookmarks )

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I didn’t know about covariance. Now it makes much more sense. However, if based on my requirements I deemed contravariance checks to be in my way, would it be possible to disable them on the higher order function instead of resolving the issue at the argument level (with a cast)? I’d like to keep the “strictFunctionTypes” flag, since it’s usually the desirable behavior. I’d be open to starting a new question if the topic is too large for the comment section

Comment: One way to do that would be to use methods instead of functions, since method parameters are bivariant: https://tsplay.dev/NVnXlN There might be more elegant solutions, but they would probably best be explored in new question, so also others can chime in.

Comment: @fedetibaldo Just one more thing I thought of: you could also parameterize the parts of `Foo` that change, which will prevent the problem altogether: https://tsplay.dev/WoqeMN